# How do I get started making unit tests for my Android app?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

This seems like a silly question but I have an app in Android Studio and I'd like to try some TDD/Unit testing. I tried adding a tests folder and adding a class manually in the explorer but found I can only add Java classes under my main src folder. How can I simply add a tests folder at the same level as my src folder and create Java classes for it? Do I need something in my build.gradle?

Comment: Seems this one is helpfull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876508/unit-tests-with-android-studio-and-gradle?rq=1

Comment: @RenjithKN this answer is getting old.

Comment: @Barodapride could you check my answer?

Comment: I followed http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support to get this going but your answer looks about the same (without the build.gradle edit though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new latest version of gradle build tools (1.3.1) came with new test functionality and I will show you how to create your test easily.

First of all there is now two default directories for tests:

[image: androidTest for Instrumentation Tests and test for Java Unit Tests]

You should put your instrumentation tests into **androidTest** and your simple JUnit tests (with almost no android dependencies) into **test**

If you wanna run your Unit Tests your have to select this option:

[image: Pure Java tests]

When you select this options your directory will be highlighted like this:
[image]

When you select instrumentation tests then you will see something like this:
[image]

You can go deep into Support Test Library checking this link:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/testing-support-library/index.html

Hope that it helps!